# Subsetting whole clusters froma dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

In my data.frame below, I wonder how to subset a whole cluster of `study` that has any `outcome` larger than `1` in it?

My desired output is shown below. I tried `subset(h, outcome > 1)` but that doesn't give my desired output.

```
h = "
study outcome
a     1
a     2
a     1
b     1
b     1 
c     3
c     3"
h = read.table(text = h,h=T)

DESIRED OUTPUT:
"
study outcome
a     1
a     2
a     1
c     3
c     3"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the `subset` -

1. subset the 'study' based on the first logical expression `outcome > 1`
2. Use `%in%` on the 'study' to create the final logical expression in `subset`

```
subset(h, study %in% study[outcome > 1])
```

-output

```
 study outcome
1     a       1
2     a       2
3     a       1
6     c       3
7     c       3
```

---

If we want to limit the number of 'study' elements having 'outcome' value 1, i.e. the first 'n' 'study', then get the `unique` 'study' from the first expression of subset, use `head` to get the first 'n' 'study' values and use `%in%` to create logical expression

```
n <- 3
subset(h, study %in% head(unique(study[outcome > 1]), n))
```

---

Or can be done with a group by approach with `any`

```
library(dplyr)
h %>%
    group_by(study) %>%
    filter(any(outcome > 1)) %>%
    ungroup
```

Comment: @rnorouzian just change `subset` to `filter`

Comment: @rnorouzian thanks, posted the answer as well